# ASP MVC - Bootstrap Partial View Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, partial-views, bootstrap-modal

I have a partial view that has *only* a bootstrap modal in it.
In the page it's called lilke this:

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialEnderecoEditModal", item) |
```

To each item of my table.
The problem is that when I select any of the items, it only shows information of the 1st one...
I have checked the generated source on the browser and in looks like this:

```
   <tr>
                        <td style="display:none" id="id">
                            94
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            rua teste
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            123
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            dhaui&#39;
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            aiujasi
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            sososo
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            sp
                        </td>                        
                        <td>
                            18000000
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <style>
    #btnEditar {
        padding: 0px;
    }
</style>
<a class="btn btn-link" id="btnEditar" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalEnderecoEdit">Editar</a>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="#ModalEnderecoEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Cadastro de Endereço</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <fieldset id="infoEndereco">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm text-box single-line" id="een_endereco" name="een_endereco" placeholder="Endereço" type="text" value="rua teste" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="een_endereco" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm text-box single-line" id="een_numero" name="een_numero" placeholder="Numero" type="text" value="123" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="een_numero" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm text-box single-line" id="een_comple" name="een_comple" placeholder="Complemento" type="text" value="dhaui&#39;" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="een_comple" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm text-box single-line" id="een_bairro" name="een_bairro" placeholder="Bairro" type="text" value="aiujasi" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="een_bairro" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm text-box single-line" id="een_cidade" name="een_cidade" placeholder="Cidade" type="text" value="sososo" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="een_cidade" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm text-box single-line" id="een_uf" name="een_uf" placeholder="Estado" type="text" value="sp" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="een_uf" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm text-box single-line" id="een_cep" name="een_cep" placeholder="CEP" type="text" value="18000000" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="een_cep" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                <button id="addEndereco" type="button" OnClick="gravarDetalheEndEdit(this);" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 |
                            <a href="/entidades/Details/94">Details</a> |
                            <a onclick="excluirUpdateDetalhe(this, 'tabEndereco', 'D');">Excluir</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="display:none" id="id">
                            95
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            rua teste2
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            151
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            jiojoij
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            joijo
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ji
                        </td>                        
                        <td>
                            18000000
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <style>
    #btnEditar {
        padding: 0px;
    }
</style>
<a class="btn btn-link" id="btnEditar" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalEnderecoEdit">Editar</a>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="#ModalEnderecoEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Cadastro de Endereço</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <fieldset id="infoEndereco">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm text-box single-line" id="een_endereco" name="een_endereco" placeholder="Endereço" type="text" value="rua teste2" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="een_endereco" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm text-box single-line" id="een_numero" name="een_numero" placeholder="Numero" type="text" value="151" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="een_numero" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm text-box single-line" id="een_comple" name="een_comple" placeholder="Complemento" type="text" value="" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="een_comple" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm text-box single-line" id="een_bairro" name="een_bairro" placeholder="Bairro" type="text" value="jiojoij" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="een_bairro" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm text-box single-line" id="een_cidade" name="een_cidade" placeholder="Cidade" type="text" value="joijo" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="een_cidade" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm text-box single-line" id="een_uf" name="een_uf" placeholder="Estado" type="text" value="ji" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="een_uf" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input class="form-control input-sm text-box single-line" id="een_cep" name="een_cep" placeholder="CEP" type="text" value="18000000" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="een_cep" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                <button id="addEndereco" type="button" OnClick="gravarDetalheEndEdit(this);" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Partial View code:

```
@model prjArqBuild.entidade_endereco
<style>
    #btnEditar {
        padding: 0px;
    }
</style>
<a class="btn btn-link" id="btnEditar" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalEnderecoEdit">Editar</a>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="#ModalEnderecoEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Cadastro de Endereço</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <fieldset id="infoEndereco">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_endereco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Endereço" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_endereco, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_numero, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Numero" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_numero, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_comple, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Complemento" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_comple, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_bairro, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Bairro" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_bairro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_cidade, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Cidade" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_cidade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_uf, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "Estado" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_uf, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.een_cep, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", placeholder = "CEP" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.een_cep, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                <button id="addEndereco" type="button" OnClick="gravarDetalheEndEdit(this);" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it renders right. But when it's called only the first one pops up. 
I think thats because of the `Modal ID` but I'm not sure.
**Does anyone have any idea?**
*If you need more details just ask, please.*

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri The example of the partial view rendered in the page

Comment: Yeah, the `id` could be problematic.  I don't like the look of having two elements with the same id on the page like that.  Can you suffix the element id with something that would uniquely identify each instance of the partial view?  That would be my first guess.

Comment: @stephen.vakil my main problem is that the partial view is rendered on every table row. And that is what I need. Is there a way to change the id dynamically or something like that?

Comment: doesn't your `item` have a property called `id` that you can use to generate it?  e.g. something like `id='@string.format("{0}#ModalEnderecoEdit", model.id)'`

Comment: @stephen.vakil Thank's! It worked! I have tried something similar with that, but it did not worked. But this way the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You've literally rendered the partial based on a particular item. Clicking a different item won't magically update that HTML. You'll need to issue an AJAX call to refetch the partial for the item that is clicked, and then insert the HTML you get back as a response into the modal's body before showing it.

Comment: I don't understand your answer.  He's calling the partial twice, passing a different item to each.  And then there's a button to activate the modal for each.  The data for the modal is different for the two items in his sample output.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to @stephen.vakil the problem was solves by changing the `id` dinamically.
The `Partial View` look like this:

```
...
    <a class="btn btn-link" id="btnEditar" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="@string.Format("#{0}ModalEnderecoEdit", Model.een_id)">Editar</a>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="@string.Format("{0}ModalEnderecoEdit", Model.een_id)" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
...
```